# Add bundle product directly to cart

Tags: cart, bundled-product, ce-1.9.2.2

We have bundled products some with flavor options some without if the bundle product doesn't have flavor options we would like the user to be able to add directly to cart from the category page `list.phtml` instead of sending them to the product page `view.phtml`.

I found a solution, I created a new attribute set and added this code around line 197 in list.phtml

```
<?php if(!$_product->canConfigure() && $_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
<?php elseif($_product->getAttributeSetId() == 15): ?>
<?php
$productAddUrl = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product);
if ($_product->getTypeId() == 'bundle'):
$bundleOptions = '?';
$selectionCollection = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection($_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($_product), $_product);
foreach($selectionCollection as $option):
$bundleOptions .= '&bundle_option[' . $option->option_id . ']=' . $option->selection_id;
$bundleOptions .= '&bundle_option_qty[' . $option->option_id . ']=' . $option->selection_qty;
endforeach;
$productAddUrl .= $bundleOptions;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: I'm have this problem. I read this article https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2434, but reference methods  $subject->setTypeHasRequiredOptions(false) and 
$subject->setRequiredOptions(false) don't exists in Product class. Now i'm try to implement methods not found and test.

Comment: I found a solution and added the code to the post.

Comment: I would like to point out  this code worked for 1.9 not sure if it'll work for 2.

Comment: Not work for me in versions 2.1.1 and 2.1.4

Comment: Yes for solution in new version you need to add **`$option->getOptionId()`** instead of `$option->option_id` and **`$option->getSelectionQty()`** instead of `$option->selection_qty`